# Is there a way to integrate gitbook and sharepoint cleanly?

Tags: sharepoint, gitbook

I have several books in Gitbook and am bouncing users from the Sharepoint based intranet to documentation in Gitbook. Is there a way to automatically embed the Gitbook content into Sharepoint so it looks like it is integrated within the intranet?

Comment: Try using the PageViewerWebPart. You could also upload the whole book to the root of a Web (namely by browsing to the Web Root using WebDav)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully integrated Gitbook into Sharepoint. Initially I tried the answer provided above, but that rendered my gitbook inside a window *within* Sharepoint which looked bad to me.

Here is the way I accomplished it:

1. Using the Gitbook CLI Toolchain installed on a linux computer, issue the `gitbook build` command.
2. Take the output from this command, which is a folder called `_book`, and upload its contents to your Sharepoint documents folder.
3. Take care to replicate the folder structure exactly. This is a bit tedious since Sharepoint doesn't allow you to upload folders (at least not my instance).
4. Rename every .html document in the `_book` folder to .aspx. This allows Users to *visit* a page when they click a link rather than *downloading* the page. If i'm not mistaken, I also had to edit the links to my books pages inside the `index.aspx` page from .html to .aspx as well.
5. Here comes the cool part... visit the link provided for the (now) `index.aspx`. Get the link by clicking the `...` button next to the file in Sharepoint. And...bingo, Sharepoint will serve your entire gitbook as a static site.

Hope this helps